# How can I write a MySQL SELECT query to find words with only and only specific characters in database?

Tags: sql, mysql, string, select, where-clause

I want to write a SELECT query in MySQL to find words with only and only specific characters in database.
For example if data is :

```
id  word
---------
1    a
2    b
3    aa
4    ab
5    aaa
6    aba
7    abc
8    abcd
9    abac
10   abaca
```

The query result to find 'a' and 'b' should be :

```
a
b
ab
```

And the query result to find 'a' and 'b' and 'a' (Repeat 'a' twice) should be :

```
a
b
aa
ab
aba
```

And the query result to find 'a' and 'b' and 'a' and 'a' (Repeat 'a' three times) should be :

```
a
b
aa
ab
aaa
aba
```

Any idea ?

```
SELECT * FROM `WORDS_table` WHERE `word` LIKE '%a%' AND `word` LIKE '%b%'
```

is not correct, because it returns all the words with any of selected characters.

NOTE : I continue to use php language to process the query result.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex:

```
select * from words where word rlike '^[ab]+$'
```

Regexp breakdown:

```
^       beginning of the string
[ab]+   1 to N occurrences of character 'a' or 'b' 
$       end of the string
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dpJT9_R4):

```
select * 
from ( values row('a'), row('ab'), row('abc'), row('abcd') ) w(word)
where word rlike '^[ab]+$'
```

| word |
| --- |
| a |
| ab |

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and helpful tutorial The query passed most of the tests successfully, but this query does not consider duplicate letters! I updated the question.